# Google Wallet API : Masked Wallet Error

Tags: android-pay

I tried to do a Google Wallet Integration , I am able to successfully use the createWalletButton API. On clicking the button , I am asked to login to Google Wallets - which is successful as well. But the call to retreive the wallet information fails. The following error is displayed:

Uh-Oh. There was a problem. Sorry, Google Wallet couldn’t complete your request. Please return to the merchant to choose a different payment method, or try again later. Error: 62 (121217125033+0530)

The same error is also seen when trying to call the requestMaskedWallet API. Please advise.

A prompt response will be helpful and much appreciated.
I am getting the error problem in Google Sample App : Instant Buy

[Downloaded Sample Instant Buy App](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/web/quickstart-cs)

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to use the Web/JS API for Instant Buy the access to Sandbox for that is to be first requested from Google - http://getinstantbuy.withgoogle.com/  after you are given sandbox access and Merchant ID etc (which you may have seen is required to be in the JWTs), you will be able to use it.

Comment: I am getting following error for Android Pay in my Production App:
Wallet error code: 51
Wallet error detail: You have not registered to use this API.

Is there anything I am missing? Any help is apprecieated